# How add ruby file to Rails application and make it auto-loadable/executable on Rails app start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, vert.x

I am trying to add some external non-rails services to my JRuby Rails application (from another framework). 
I want to run a Ruby file in the context of my Rails Application  and make it auto-loadable/executable on Rails app start.

I didn't  find the answer on Stackoverflow yet, the closest I have found so far is the suggestion to use  rake tasks.

But i want it to be something like this:

In   my

```
/app
```

directory   besides  controllers, models, views  folders

I want to have something like:

```
   /app/services
```

and in this services folder to have some

```
service_a.rb
service_b.rb 
service_c.rb
```

so that when I start the Rails application,   RAILS  autoload those files from   /services   folder       and executes them. 
I  have read this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

But it didn't help,  it was just naming conventions and name space constants.

I want to have in my rails app something  like entrypoint  (like in C   /  Java)  from where I load and execute  some  additional logic, that doesn't belog to rails   (Vertx.io   verticles deployment)

or to have  some    **app.rb**  "main Class, method"   from where I would load  my /services   and execute them

```
# app.rb
require 'vertx/vertx'
vertx = Vertx::Vertx.vertx()

# deploy verticles                    or  vertx.deploy_verticle("verticles/myverticle.js")
puts " @@@@@   I am about to deploy verticles! "
vertx.deployVerticle("verticles/listener.rb")
puts " verticle  listener.rb has been deployed i think"
vertx.deployVerticle("verticles/sender.rb")
puts " verticle  sender.rb has been deployed i think"
```

**UPDATE**

thank you for suggesting the configs of application.rb
I have just configured it the way you suggested:

```
# /config/application.rb
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Workspace
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true

    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/services/*"]
  end
end
```

Then I have created the directory  /app/services

Placed 2 files in there:    service_a.rb   and service_b.rb

I just want to make sure that the code in service_a.rb  gets exectued. 
So that I for example print stuff out to console.

My   service_a.rb:

```
# service_a.rb

puts "Service A has been exectued FROM PUTS method from services/service_a.rb "

class ServiceA
    def service_a_method
        puts " Service_A_METHOD has been exectued from services/service_a.rb ServiceA CLASS "
    end
end

def stand_alone_service_a_method
    puts " stand_alone_service_a_method  has been just exectued !!! "
end


stand_alone_service_a_method()
```

Then i go ahead and run   bin/rails  server
(I am using C9.IO  cloud 9  web IDE and ubuntu container with rails 4.2)

```
    javajedi:~/workspace $ bin/rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2017-03-25 16:07:25] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2017-03-25 16:07:25] INFO  ruby 2.3.0 (2015-12-25) [x86_64-linux]
[2017-03-25 16:07:25] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2413 port=3000
```

but as you see, nothing gets printed out to console. Is that that i haven't set up ENV to be DEV so that it allows that stuff to be printed in console? 
I just wanna be sure that my code gets exectued. 
Because I am gonna deploy Vertx.io  Verticles via such small services files.

Please advice what do I do wrong?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html).

Comment: Have you tried adding the executable script in your initializer directory?

Comment: DiodonHystrix, thank you for the link!  I will read it through!

Olalekan Sogunle, thank you for your suggestion with initializer,  I have placed there and it worked!
But is there more beautiful way to do that?  Not in initializer, but in the folder of my choice under /app   ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the sub directory in `application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/services/*"]
```

Comment: shiladitya,   thank you for advice!  I have just trried it config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/services/*"]   (please see update above)  and still i can't see any output to cosnole.